# Powershell Foreach loop through dictionary with results to another dictionary. I can do with for loop, & in python with foreach but not powershell

Tags: powershell, dictionary, foreach

```
$scores = [ordered]@{
Jack = 81;
Mike = 78;
Mark = 99;
Jim = 64;
}

$grades = [ordered]@{}

$len = $scores.Count
for ($n=0;$n -lt $len; $n++){
    if ($($scores.values)[$n] -gt 65){
        $grades += @{$($scores.keys)[$n] = $($scores.keys)[$n]}
        $grades[$n] = $($scores.values)[$n] = "PASS"
    }
else{
    $grades += @{$($scores.keys)[$n] = $($scores.keys)[$n]}
    $grades[$n] = $($scores.values)[$n] = "FAIL"
}
}

$grades
```

=======THE ABOVE WORKS IN POWERSHELL JUST FINE

*******BELOW IS THE PROBLEM IN POWERSHELL (This structure works in Python)

```
$scores = [ordered]@{
Jack = 81;
Mike = 78;
Mark = 99;
Jim = 64;

}

$grades = [ordered]@{}

foreach($key in $scores){
    if ($scores[$key] -gt 65){
        $grades[$key] = "PASS"
    }
    else{
        $grades[$key] = "FAIL"
    }
}

$grades
```

======== Here is the correct FOR loop output:[image: Expected Output from For]

******** Here is the output from FOREACH:[image: Current Output from Foreach]

Please show me how the FOREACH loop is failing.

(Any improvement on the FOR loop is frosting on the cake!)

Comment: `hashtable` is not an iterable type in .NET, so `$key` is the whole dict, not its key.  What you're trying to do in effect is index into `$scores` using a `hashtable` which returns `$null` because it doesn't exist and that's coerced to `0` by your `-gt` comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreach` example is missing either [`.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#displaying-hash-tables) (recommended to use `.PSBase.Keys`) or [`.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#sorting-keys-and-values) in order to enumerate it:

```
$scores = [ordered]@{
    Jack = 81
    Mike = 78
    Mark = 99
    Jim  = 64
}

# - Using `.PSBase.Keys`

$grades = [ordered]@{}
foreach($key in $scores.PSBase.Keys) {
    if ($scores[$key] -gt 65) {
        $grades[$key] = "PASS"
        continue
    }
    $grades[$key] = "FAIL"
}

# - Using `.GetEnumerator()`

$grades = [ordered]@{}
foreach($pair in $scores.GetEnumerator()) {
    if ($pair.Value -gt 65) {
        $grades[$pair.Key] = "PASS"
        continue
    }
    $grades[$pair.Key] = "FAIL"
}
```

Comment: _Why_ would you use `psbase`?

Comment: Thanks again Santiago, you da man!

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley well, it's either `PSBase.Keys` (which is documented in PS MS Docs) or `.get_Keys()`. The main reason is, if you add a Key to the hash with name `Keys` then you no longer can call the `Keys` property

Comment: my pleasure @colemd1 happy to help